# Test if marker from Json is Inviewport

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to test whether a loaded marker via jSon is already on the map or not !

```
$.each( data.markers, function(i, m) {
            if($("#map-canvas").gmap("inViewport",m))===false){
                $("#map-canvas").gmap("addMarker", { "position": new google.maps.LatLng(m.lat, m.lng),"animation": google.maps.Animation.DROP},function(){})})
```

but the `$("#map-canvas").gmap("inViewport",m)` doesn't seem to get the marker.
It seems that the m is not a marker, I want to find out if the marker already exists on vieport
Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, a extra parenthesis, see:

```
if($("#map-canvas").gmap("inViewport",m))===false){
                                        ^--- REMOVE THIS
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It was a stupid mistake , but fixing it doesn't fix the problem , 
I get this message : 
TypeError: d.getPosition is not a function in the jquery file.

Comment: I'm testing with :
    alert($("#map-canvas").gmap("inViewport",m));